# ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in weights, estimation infeasible.in GLM Statsmodels

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, glm, training-data

I got this message:

**ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in weights, estimation infeasible.**

```
frequency_poisson_model_var_weights = sm.GLM(endog=train_labels, exog=train_features.astype(float), family=sm.families.Poisson()), var_weights=train_exposures)
frequency_poisson_results_var_weights = frequency_poisson_model_var_weights.fit()
```

When I change the fit method to 'lbfgs' it works for me but I need the default method.

In addition, I tried to remove the var_weights parameter and that didn't fix it too..
any suggestions?

Traceback:

> 1209 self.weights = (self.iweights * self.n_trials *    1210
> self.family.weights(mu))    1211 wlsendog = (lin_pred +
> self.family.link.deriv(mu) * (self.endog-mu)    1212             -
> self._offset_exposure)
> -> 1213 wls_mod = reg_tools._MinimalWLS(wlsendog, wlsexog,    1214                                 self.weights, check_endog=True,    1215
> check_weights=True)    1216 wls_results =
> wls_mod.fit(method=wls_method)    1217 lin_pred = np.dot(self.exog,
> wls_results.params)
>
> File
> ~/wd/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/_tools.py:48,
> in _MinimalWLS.**init**(self, endog, exog, weights, check_endog,
> check_weights)
> 46 if check_weights:
> 47     if not np.all(np.isfinite(w_half)):
> ---> 48         raise ValueError(self.msg.format('weights'))
> 50 if check_endog:
> 51     if not np.all(np.isfinite(endog)):
>
> ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in weights, estimation
> infeasible.

[Image of the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIe6J.png)

Comment: you need to show the last part of the traceback that shows where the exception has been raised. If a different optimizer works, then you could use the estimated params as start_params for the estimation.

Comment: @Josef I added what you asked for.. thanks :)